# How to create an executable python file in command prompt on windows 10

Tags: python

I'm reading an introductory book on python and the example code

**$ cat hello.py**

**print('Hello world!')**

doesn't work (doesn't print Hello world!) after I type

**$ python hello.py**

I have python properly installed and working
and I have tried using "type" instead of "cat"

Please help!

Comment: What exactly happens?

Comment: Does Windows give you an error or does Python give you an error?

Comment: there's error message when I press return after **cat hello.py** saying that **cat** is not recognized as executable file and because of this i cannot input **print('Hello world!')** next

Comment: Neither `cat` on Unix or `type` on Windows has anything to do with creating an executable file.

Comment: i'm confused about what does and does not work. `cat` or `type` just prints out the script. You say it doesn't work.... well, what happens? `python hello.py` runs the program. Once again, if it doesn't work, what happens?

Comment: there's error message when I press return after **cat hello.py** saying that cat is not recognized as executable command and because of this i cannot input **print('Hello world!')** next @tdelaney

Comment: Okay, on windows you use `type hello.py` to display an existing file. You say you cannot input stuff next... that program isn't used to input stuff, just display stuff. Do you have a text editor you can use?

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you. Well, I am not sure, but I think that the point of the author is to show how to write a simple program in a command prompt and then run it right there without writing and saving a program in a text editor first (which I can do )

Comment: An option, then, it to just run `python`. It brings up a shell. You may find on windows that running `py` works. Also, if you can get to `idle`, its doing the same thing you can write code right there.

Comment: @Vallentin What does then?

Comment: What OS are you on?  **cat** is a UNIX command, and doesn't mean anything on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the redirection.  You need

```
$ cat > hello.py
```

You will now get a prompt of **>**.  Type your program, one line at a time, and hit CTRL-D when you're done.  The stuff you typed is now in **hello.py**.  At this point,

```
$ python hello.py
```

should run your program.

Comment: I get access denied message after i type 'cat > hello.py'

Comment: Any other suggestions?